# Merging a custom field with a link

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, custom-field, merge, custom-link

OK, so here is what I am trying to do:

Right now when a person requests a quote, I automate using Zapier to bring in the contact information to a contact card.  These quotes require our sales team to have to take this information, research and send them a quote. We have a way to automate it by having customers just click on a link.

This will reduce our sales team data entry process by 20%

So my question is can I merge a custom field from Salesforce to ExactTarget that has a link, and can I take that merged field and add it under a button via html?

```
<a> <img src="button.jpg"> <href="%mergedfield%"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could do something like this:

```
%%[
var @mergedfield
set @mergedfield = AttributeValue("mergedfield")
]%%

<a href="%%=redirectto(@mergedfield)=%%" alias="this is the mergedfield">
  <img src="http://www.degdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/deg_logo.png">
</a>
```

Reference: [AMPScript Functions](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/#alphalist)